# My Link with href doesn't scroll even though the link changes. Nextjs

Tags: next.js, href, next-link

I'm working on a react with nextjs project.
I'm using Link to scroll to a specific section on the same page.

Here is one of the components that use Link:

```
import styles from './section1.module.scss';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import tought_process from '../../../public/thought_process.png';
import Link from 'next/link';

const Section1 = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.left}>
        <div className={styles.leftContainer}>

          <Link href='#enews'>
            <div className={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <Button className={styles.buttonstyle1}>Get started</Button>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.right}>
        <Image
          src={tought_process}
          className={styles.imageStyle}
          alt='how to think about organizing'
          layout='responsive'
          priority
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Section1;
```

And here i mark the element with the id:

```
      <div {...handlers} className={styles.bigBody}>
        <NavBar open={menuOpen} toggle={setMenuOpen} scrollY={scrollY} />

        <SideMenu open={menuOpen} toggle={setMenuOpen} scrollY={scrollY} />

        <div className={styles.sections}>
          <Section1 />
          <Section2 />
          <Section3 id='enews' />
          <Section4 />
        </div>
```

Can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple clickable elements are wrapping each other. Remove the `button` and add the [anchor element](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag).

```js
<Link href="#enews">
 <a>Get started</a>
</Link>
```

```js
<Link href="#enews">
 <a className={styles.buttonContainer}>
  <span className={styles.buttonstyle1}>Get started</span>
 </a>
</Link>
```

I'd recommend updating the styles so you can remove the inner `span` element.

---

I use a custom link component that does a few things (not shown); one is smooth scroll to hash routes if the browser supports smooth scrolling (not Safari).

```js
import NextLink, { LinkProps } from "next/link";
import { HTMLProps, MouseEvent, FC } from "react";

export const Link: FC<LinkProps & HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>> = ({ as, children, href, replace, scroll, shallow, passHref, ...rest}) => {
  const onClick = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => {
    if (href.startsWith("#")) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const destination = document.getElementById(href.substring(1));
      if (destination) destination.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
  };
  return (
    <NextLink as={as} href={href} passHref={passHref} replace={replace} scroll={scroll} shallow={shallow}>
      <a href={href} {...rest} onClick={onClick}>
        {children}
      </a>
    </NextLink>
  );
};
```

*I removed new lines to condense the code block*

If you went with the above approach, don't include the `anchor` tag since it's automatically included.

```js
import { Link } from "./custom/path/link"

<Link href="#enews">Get started</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two points here:

1. As per the nextjs, [passHref](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag) has to be used if a custom element is used as a child of Link tag instead of an anchor tag.
2. As per the same docs value of href should be '/#enews' not '#enews'

Comment: tried to add slash and passed the href. neither of those work unfortunately

Comment: even tried removing the button and his container. even with plain text doesnt scroll

Answer (score 0):

In order to scroll to a specific section, both linking component and section should be in the same component (or inner component).
Otherwise use the full page url followed by the id.

Example: Link href='/pagename/#id'>Navigate

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of NextJS and their  component, you need to set the [`scroll` prop to `false`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link#scroll). This is because the behavior by default will try to scroll to the top of the page after a navigation.

Example usage:

```js
<Link
  href="#sign-up"
  className="text-xl font-medium text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-800"
  scroll={false}
>
  Archor Text
</Link>
```

Also, using `<a>` tags within the `<Link>` component is [deprecated](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link#legacybehavior) now.

I wrote a little more in depth about it when using [smooth scroll with Tailwind and NextJS here](https://mariogiancini.com/implementing-smooth-scroll-behavior-with-tailwind-css-and-nextjs).